# Get rid of Windows typical styles?

Tags: java, windows, swing, winapi

I will start developing application for Windows. But I want to get rid of the cancel button and the typical Windows format like:

[image]

And I want it to look something like that, get rid of windows format and design my application in my own way.

[image]

So, will somebody suggest me, how to do that? I searched so much but cannot find any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this app. is written using the Swing GUI toolkit, it is as simple as either using a [`JWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html), or calling [`Frame.setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell what language your question is, here is answer for C++ for WinAPI:

Create your window like that:

```
HWND       hWnd;
WNDCLASS WndCls;

// Create the application window
WndCls.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
WndCls.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcedure;
WndCls.cbClsExtra    = 0;
WndCls.cbWndExtra    = 0;
WndCls.hIcon         = NULL;
WndCls.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
WndCls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
WndCls.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
WndCls.lpszClassName = _T("WndClassName");
WndCls.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

// Register the window class
RegisterClass(&WndCls);

hWnd = CreateWindow(_T("MyWnd"),
  _T("WndClassName"),
  WS_BORDER,
  CW_USEDEFAULT,
  CW_USEDEFAULT,
  CW_USEDEFAULT,
  CW_USEDEFAULT,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  ::GetModuleHandle(0),
  NULL);
```

and then:

```
::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);
```

you will have a white rectangle app which you will be able to paint however you like.

Also, you can spy on window styles using Spy++ from Visual Studio package

Answer (score 0):

It's called the Titlebar. Hide it by removing the form border style.

```
this.FormBorderStyle= System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```